# How to create only one Model and pass it through web app in MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

I have a model what is connecting to physical hardware (ATEM Mini), then controller and view. My problem is that every time I am pressing button on View to change something on hardware model is creating again and connecting to hardware again.

Edit:
That's a problem because after calling switcher.changeInput(switcher) few Times, model is creating and connecting again to hardware and after few connecting it starts to refuse it. Is it possible to pass one connected model through the view?

Model:

```
        private IBMDSwitcher switcher;
        private IBMDSwitcherMixEffectBlock me0;
        public int camera { get; set; }
        public AtemSwitcher()
        {
            // Connect to switcher
            IBMDSwitcherDiscovery discovery = new CBMDSwitcherDiscovery();
            discovery.ConnectTo("192.168.0.10", out IBMDSwitcher switcher, out _BMDSwitcherConnectToFailure failureReason);
            this.switcher = switcher;
            me0 = this.MixEffectBlocks.First();
        }

        static long GetInputId(IBMDSwitcherInput input)
        {
            input.GetInputId(out long id);
            return id;
        }

        private static IBMDSwitcherInput getSwitcherInput(AtemSwitcher sw, int cam)
        {
            return sw.SwitcherInputs
                                        .Where((i, ret) => {
                                            i.GetPortType(out _BMDSwitcherPortType type);
                                            return type == _BMDSwitcherPortType.bmdSwitcherPortTypeExternal;
                                        })
                                        .ElementAt(cam);
        }

        public void changeInput(AtemSwitcher sw)
        { 
            me0.SetProgramInput(GetInputId(getSwitcherInput(sw, camera)));
        }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Atem()
        {
            AtemSwitcher sw = new AtemSwitcher();
            return View("Connection", sw);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Connection(AtemSwitcher switcher)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                i = 10;
                switcher.changeInput(switcher);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@model pokus222.Models.AtemSwitcher
<h1>Atem control</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Connection">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="camera" class="control-label"></label>
                <br />
                <input asp-for="camera" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="camera" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Přepni" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are sending an HTTP Request from client to server (hardware) and getting back a Response.  If the client makes a change than the change has to be sent to the server to update.  A successful Request will return a Response with a 200 OK, or an error response.  You have to determine what is causing the error and fix the error.  The solution is not blocking a new request.

Comment: The request that i send to server return 200 OK, but after 5 this request, the problem is showed in "discovery.ConnectTo("192.168.0.10", out IBMDSwitcher switcher, out _BMDSwitcherConnectToFailure failureReason);" as en "error HRESULT E_FAIL". In my opinion the problem is this multiple connecting to server. If i make console app where i have created only one model and work with it, there is no problem.

Comment: With HTTP the connection does not stay open.  You send a request, get back a response and then connection closes. "HRESULT E_FAIL" is a general failure message with no specific cause.  You need to debug.  Running commands in parallel can cause issues.  If you only have one hard device how can you have multiple models?

Comment: I dont know, the problem is the MVC i think. Every click on View (website) cause calling new Model and model calls new connection.

Answer (score 0):

I need one question answered
What does switcher.changeInput() do?  Does it just change the model, or make a connection, or both?

I'm assuming it makes a connection.  If so, it should use same connection as discovery.ConnectTo().  You should only have one connection at a time. Either Open the connection before switcher.changeInput() and close connection after discovery.ConnectTo().  Or have both methods close connection when done.

The code you posted is a Controller at the client.  Controllers can be at both client and server.  A controller is used with HTTP where you send one request and get back one response and the connection closes.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  You are connecting to the hardware using IBMDSwitcherDiscovery which is TCP.  Every time you send a Request you are making a new Connection but never closing the connection.

What you are doing is commonly called "HTTP over IP".  Your are using HTTP protocol where you send a request and get back a response.  You are using as your transport layer TCP.  Your request is being done with switcher.changeInput().  Your response is being done with discovery.ConnectTo().

Here is a high level description of what should happen in Client

1. Need to initialize the hardware or get current settings
2. Display the initial settings in a view
3. Change Setting(s)
   a) Change Model (change switch settings) and updating model with switcher.changeInput(switcher)
   b) Send a Request (Open Connection) and send model
   c) Get Response which is the model returned in the OUT from discovery.ConnectTo()
   d) Display new settings in a view
   e) Close Connection

The IActionResult is the body of a HTTP Request/Response.  With a controller it is the serialize body data.

Your view is taking the IActionResult and display results.

You have one model. The switcher which is used in both the request and response.  You first change the switch settings.  Then send the request with model switcher using discovery.ConnectTo().  The Response is the OUT switcher which you then view.

The OUT switch should be what you send with next request since it is the current setting of the switch.

Comment: switcher.changeInput() change the camera input in hardware. Its a method in model. I wil add teh code to task.

Comment: Doesn't it need to make a connection to the hardware?  I do not see the connection.

Comment: If i wouldnt do a connection, i cannot control it.

Comment: You should only have one connection at a time.  I think you have more than one and trying to find out where all the connection are coming from.

Comment: Thats the point I dont understant. I dont know why it makes new and new connections.

Comment: I would check the documentation.  Camera can be connected over IP or on a USB cable.  It looks like the code you have is using USB instead of IP.  It is asking for a camera integer.  From code posted I do not know where the number would come from if you are using an IP.

Comment: I think the number is not the point. And i cannot use USB cause its not connected.

Comment: I tried getting more info at vendors site.  Found your posting for help.